# How to set Modelstate error keys to camel case?

Tags: c#, json.net, asp.net-web-api2, .net-framework-version, modelstate

How do I set the modelstate keys to camel case in WEB Api .net framework.

I use JsonProperty attribute to set the property names to camel case.
Now I want the modelstate to be the same as the json (camel case) how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 3):

You can do it as follows:

```
.AddJsonOptions(options =>
{
    options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver
    {
        NamingStrategy = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy
        {
            ProcessDictionaryKeys = true
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: It solves my issue. It was very useful! Thank you. I think, it must be the answer.

Comment: I see that this is available and works on NewtonsoftJson, but I can't seem to find the equivalent extensibility point for System.Text.Json on dotnet 3.1 (the new library provided by Microsoft to replace Newtonsoft). Is anybody aware of a way to do this with the newer library?

Comment: @r3gularJ0hn Try options.JsonSerializerOptions.DictionaryKeyPolicy

Answer (score 1):

When configuring MVC in your `ConfigureServices()`, replace the `ContractResolver`:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
    services.AddMvc()
        .AddJsonOptions(options => options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver());
}
```